# CSS z-index не работает при двух блоках absolute

Tags: html, css, css3

Добрый день, у меня есть слайдер

```
  <section class="slider">
    <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
                        <div class="text">
                                <span>TECHNIK <p>LOGISTYK</p></span>
                        </div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
      </ul>
                <div class="logoty">

                </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

class logoty это блок который при изменении картинки остается поверх нее, а класс text должно быть видно поверх класса logoty.
Тут показано что у меня вышло
[текст ниже фона](http://savepic.ru/13193087.png)

[текст который должен быть выше](http://savepic.ru/13188991.png)
Вот еще код CSS

```
.logoty{
  width: 480px;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text{
  z-index: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.slides{
  position: relative;
}

.slides li{

  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

на трёх блоках работает

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 20px;
}

.b,
.c,
.d {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.b {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: blue;
  z-index: 80;
}

.c {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -40%);
  background: red;
  z-index: 90;
}

.d {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-30%, -30%);
  background: grey;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```